# Routing to different default action for different controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using the default routing below.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "17" }
```

The problem is that it's very rigid. The default action will be *Index* in each case. (And the default controller will be *Home*.)

I'd like to route to action *IndexHey* when controller *Uno* is targeted and to action *IndexHoopla* when *Duo* is. What is the syntax for that?!

*(I've played around with different additional route mappings but didn't got it to work and now I'm sick and tired of trial-and-erroring.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach is to have specific routes for specific controllers *before* generic one like

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Uno",
  url: "Uno/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Uno", action = "IndexHoopls", id = "17" }
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "17" }
```

Comment: Is it recommended to call both routings *Default*? I'd use *Uno*, *Duo* etc.

Comment: @KonradViltersten - copy-paste... I don't believe you can have duplicate names (can't check right now). Updated the sample.